# How can I do the "Stop" button in Android?

Tags: android, audio

I'm creating an app for android using mediaplayer.  I just created the "play", and the pause button.  Here is my code:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.iinfancia);

try {
    player.prepare();
}
catch (Exception e) {
}

play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        player.start();
    }
});

pausar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
    public void onClick(View arg0) { 
        player.pause();
    } 
});
```

Now I want to know, how do I make the "stop" button, because when I do this:

```
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) { 
        player.stop();
    }
});
```

The song stop, but when I click at "Play" again, the sound doesn't start.

Answer (score 2):

Use player.pause() instead.  Just like a cd player, stop ends playback permanently, pause lets you restart from that point.